# Custom Posts on homepage

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm just getting my feet wet with creating a custom post type (which is up and running). I'd like to display the CPT alongside other posts on my homepage... I can't figure it out for the life of me. I'm hoping someone can see the error of my ways before I pull more hair out. I'm sure it's a rookie mistake,  I have been staring at the screen perhaps a little too long... any help would be appreciated!

I've also come across a few articles suggesting pre_get_posts isn't a good idea.

I'm using a Woothemes Canvas Child Theme

---

Have a page called Home that uses the Canvas Magazine Template

so...

```
 function review_post() {

$labels = array(
      'name'=> _x( 'Reviews', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
      etc....

);

    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'=> 'review',
    etc...

);

$args = array(
     'label'               => __( 'post_review_key', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'         => __( 'Posts for Review Snippets', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', ),
    'taxonomies'          => array( 'reviews'),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'menu_icon'           => '/review-star-16x16.jpg',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',

);
    register_post_type( 'post_review_key', $args );

}

 // Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'review_post', 0 );

}
```

and then

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );

function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'review_post' ) );
return $query;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'post_review_key' ) )` ?

Comment: I tried that, didn't work for me.

Comment: If you're homepage is using `frontpage.php` you will need to use `is_front_page()` instead of `is_home()`. Also if you want to display a separate query of a custom post type, read into [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: if you're using a static page with a custom template, it's likely the query which loads your posts is not the main query, so a hook on `pre_get_posts` won't work in this case. you'll have to look at the template to see how that query is being performed, you'll probably have to override the template in your child theme and modify the query directly within the template. this is probably a question for woo support anyway.

Comment: I think he just wants to include cpts on his post page with regular posts.

Comment: but this doesn't sound like the posts page - *Have a page called Home that uses the Canvas Magazine Template*

Comment: Correct Milo, that's what I'm hoping for. Just occurred to me that might have to do something to the Magazine template...

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with both these code snippets and it will work.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_post_types_to_loop' );

function add_custom_post_types_to_loop( $query ) {
if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'reviews' ) );
return $query;
}
```

review is the name of your CPT slug not review_post

**Note:** I have redone the code and changed the name and slug to reviews.

Plus you're using the same function name review_post as the post_type which may cause problems. You have also added a taxonomy named the same

Here's the code that works:

```
add_action( 'init', 'new_post_type' );
function new_post_type() {

register_post_type( 'reviews',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name'          => __( 'Reviews', 'wpsites' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Review', 'wpsites' ),
        ),
'label'               => __( 'Reviews', 'text_domain' ),
'description'         => __( 'Posts for Review Snippets', 'text_domain' ),
'labels'              => $labels,
'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', ),
'taxonomies'          => array( 'review-type' ),
'hierarchical'        => false,
'public'              => true,
'show_ui'             => true,
'show_in_menu'        => true,
'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
'menu_position'       => 5,
'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-images-alt2',
'can_export'          => true,
'has_archive'         => true,
'exclude_from_search' => false,
'publicly_queryable'  => true,
'rewrite'      => array( 'slug' => 'reviews', 'with_front' => false ),
'capability_type'     => 'page',

));

}
```

[image]

The above code goes in the custom function section of the functions.php file for the Canvas theme or a child themes functions file.

The code has been tested on the Canvas theme and also displays single cpts in the main posts page loop.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: great! Thanks Brad. This works if I have Setttings >> Reading >> Front Page Displays Latest Posts. What aiming for is to have a static front page (i'll just call it "Test Page" for now) that uses the Magazine template that will show all posts, CPTs included. I edited my original post to reflect this about 20min after I posted.

Comment: It does. I tested it using the Magazine template on the front page.

Comment: hmm... it doesn't work for me. Perhaps I missed a step: I have Front Page Displays: A Static Page (page = Test Page - w/ Magazine Template), and no page chosen for posts. Only normal posts show (on the page and in Recent Posts widget, which perhaps is a different issue altogether). If I've missed a step, that might explain. Thanks so far!

Comment: You need to select a page to display posts

Answer (score 0):

Try this, should work:

```
function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'post_review_key' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );
```